# How can I check if a file is actively open in another process outside of my python script with python3.9 in Windows 10?

Tags: python, linux, macos, windows-10, pid

I am using the following function to allow the OS to open a third party application associated with the filetype in question.  For example:  If variable 'fileToOpen' links to a file (it's full path of course) called flower.psd, this function would open up Photoshop in Windows and Gimp in Linux (typically).

```
def launchFile(fileToOpen):
    if platform.system() == 'Darwin':       # macOS
        subprocess.call(('open', fileToOpen))
    elif platform.system() == 'Windows':    # Windows
        os.startfile(fileToOpen)
    else:                                   # linux variants
        subprocess.call(('xdg-open', fileToOpen))
```

While it is running, I want to have the same python script monitor the use of that file and delete it once the third party app is done using it (meaning...the 3rd party app closed the psd file or the third party app itself closed and released the file from use).

I've tried using psutil and pywin32 but neither seem to work in Windows 10 with Python3.9.  Does anyone have any success with this?  If so, how did you go about getting the process of the third party app while not getting a permission error from Windows?

Ideally, I would like to get a solution that works across Windows, Macs, and Linux but I'll take any help with Windows 10 for now since Mac and Linux can be found easier with commandline assistance with the ***ps -ax | grep %filename%*** command

Keep in mind, this would ideally track any file.  TIA for your help.

Update by request:
I tried adding this code to mine (from a previous suggestion).  Even this alone in a python test.py file spits out permission errors:

```
import psutil


for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    try:
        # this returns the list of opened files by the current process
        flist = proc.open_files()
        if flist:
            print(proc.pid,proc.name)
            for nt in flist:
                print("\t",nt.path)

    # This catches a race condition where a process ends
    # before we can examine its files    
    except psutil.NoSuchProcess as err:
        print("****",err)
```

The follow code below does not spit out an error but does not detect a file in use:

```
import psutil
from pathlib import Path

def has_handle(fpath):
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        try:
            for item in proc.open_files():
                if fpath == item.path:
                    return True
        except Exception:
            pass

    return False

thePath = Path("C:\\Users\\someUser\\Downloads\\Book1.xlsx")    
fileExists = has_handle(thePath)

if fileExists :
    print("This file is in use!")
else :
    print("This file is not in use")
```

Comment: Please show the code you have tried so far (using psutil and pywin32), even if it didn't work.

Comment: Thanks for checking in @GordonAitchJay .  I've updated my post with the two code samples I've tried thus far.

Answer (score 1):

Found it!
The original recommendation from another post forgot one function..."Path"  The item.path from the process list is returned as a string. This needs to convert to a Path object for comparison of your own path object.

Therefore this line:

```
if fpath == item.path:
```

Should be:

```
if fpath == Path(item.path):
```

and here is the full code:

```
import psutil
from pathlib import Path

def has_handle(fpath):
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        try:
            for item in proc.open_files():
                print (item.path)
                if fpath == Path(item.path):
                    return True
        except Exception:
            pass

    return False

thePath = Path("C:\\Users\\someUser\\Downloads\\Book1.xlsx")    
fileExists = has_handle(thePath)

if fileExists :
    print("This file is in use!")
else :
    print("This file is not in use")
```

**Note:** The reason to use Path objects rather than a string is to stay OS independant.

Comment: Cool. Why do you need to delete the file as soon as the program is done with it? `has_handle` takes quite a while. Would it work if you called `os.remove` in an infinite loop until it succeeds? Sleep for 100ms between attempts.

Comment: Also, consider using raw strings when working with Windows filepaths. For example `thePath = Path(r"C:\Users\someUser\Downloads\Book1.xlsx")`

Comment: @GordonAitchJay.  I delete it because it's a temporary file for overall project.  has_handle is slow but fast enough for the purpose.  You're os.remove loop might work.  I hadn't thought of that. I'd have to test with something unique like Excel and it's method of duplicating to a temp-file and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Frankie 's answer I put together this script. The script **above** took **16.1** seconds per file as `proc.open_files()` is quite slow.

The script below checks all files in a directory and returns the pid related to each open file. 17 files only took **2.9s** to check. This is due to only calling proc.open_files() if the files default app is open in memory.

As this is used to check if a folder can be moved, the pid can be later used to **force** close the locking application but BEWARE that that application could have other documents open and all data would be lost.

This does not detect open txt files or may not detect files that dont have a default application

```py
from pathlib import Path
import psutil
import os
import shlex
import winreg
from pprint import pprint as pp
from collections import defaultdict


class CheckFiles():
    def check_locked_files(self, path: str):
        '''Check all files recursivly in a directory and return a dict with the
           locked files associated with each pid (proocess id) 

        Args:
            path (str): root directory

        Returns:
            dict: dict(pid:[filenames])
        '''
        fnames = []
        apps = set()
        for root, _, f_names in os.walk(path):
            for f in f_names:
                f = Path(os.path.join(root, f))
                if self.is_file_in_use(f):
                    default_app = Path(self.get_default_windows_app(f.suffix)).name
                    apps.add(default_app)
                    fnames.append(str(f))
        if apps:
            return self.find_process(fnames, apps)

    def find_process(self, fnames: list[str], apps: set[str]):
        '''find processes for each locked files

        Args:
            fnames (list[str]): list of filepaths
            apps (set[str]): set of default apps

        Returns:
            dict: dict(pid:[filenames])
        '''
        open_files = defaultdict(list)
        for p in psutil.process_iter(['name']):
            name = p.info['name']
            if name in apps:
                try:
                    [open_files[p.pid].append(x.path) for x in p.open_files() if x.path in fnames]
                except:
                    continue
        return dict(open_files)
        

    def is_file_in_use(self, file_path: str):
        '''Check if file is in use by trying to rename it to its own name (nothing changes) but if
           locked then this will fail

        Args:
            file_path (str): _description_

        Returns:
            bool: True is file is locked by a process
        '''
        path = Path(file_path)
        
        if not path.exists():
            raise FileNotFoundError
        try:
            path.rename(path)
        except PermissionError:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    
    def get_default_windows_app(self, suffix: str):
        '''Find the default app dedicated to a file extension (suffix)

        Args:
            suffix (str): ie ".jpg"

        Returns:
            None|str: default app exe
        '''
        try:
            class_root = winreg.QueryValue(winreg.HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, suffix)
            with winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, r'{}\shell\open\command'.format(class_root)) as key:
                command = winreg.QueryValueEx(key, '')[0]
                return shlex.split(command)[0]
        except:
            return None
        

old_dir = r"C:\path_to_dir"

c = CheckFiles()
r = c.check_locked_files(old_dir)
pp(r)
```